# Java - Recorrer Array varias dimensiones

Tags: java, array

necesito recorrer este array y no me sale

```
    String[][]  gastos = {{"Cafe","23/8/22","560$"},{"Coca","20/8/22","300$"},
                        {"Empanadas","10/8/22","800$"},{"Vino","15/8/22","700$"}};
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < gastos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(gastos[i]);
                
    }
```

Necesitaría que la salida sea la siguiente:

```
Cafe 23/8/22 560$,
Coca 20/8/22 300$,
Empanadas 10/8/22 800$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de ralizarlo, por ejemplo:

```
 String[][]  gastos = {{"Cafe","23/8/22","560$"},{"Coca","20/8/22","300$"},
                {"Empanadas","10/8/22","800$"},{"Vino","15/8/22","700$"}};

Arrays.stream(gastos).forEach((i) -> {
Arrays.stream(i).forEach((j) -> System.out.print(j + " "));
System.out.println();
});
```

la salida sería:

```
Cafe 23/8/22 560$ 
Coca 20/8/22 300$ 
Empanadas 10/8/22 800$ 
Vino 15/8/22 700$
```

---

Otro método:

```
    //Bucle a traves de todas las filas
    for (int i = 0; i < gastos.length; i++){
        // Recorrer todos los elementos de la fila actual
        for (int j = 0; j < gastos[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(gastos[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

tendría como salida:

```
Cafe 23/8/22 560$ 
Coca 20/8/22 300$ 
Empanadas 10/8/22 800$ 
Vino 15/8/22 700$
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicional al for que recorre el array gastos necesitas otro que recorra los array guardados en este

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gastos.length; i++) {//recorre gastos
       for (int j=0;j<gastos[i].length;j++ ) {//recorre arrays guardado en gastos 
          System.out.print(gastos[i][j]+" ");
       }System.out.println("");
                
    }
```

tambien podrias haces uso del metodo `deepToString()`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(gastos));
```

o usar Lambda java+8

```
 Arrays.stream(gastos).forEach(p->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p)));
```